# How can i flip an element on click adding a class?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Can someone help me with a animation for flipping div? More exact i want to add a class on click with jquery that animate the flip in one directin and at the next click removes the old class and and a new one for the new background-image and new flip direction.

```
<style>
div{height:150px; width:150px; border:1px solid black; border-radius:10px;
    background-size:100% 100%;}
.face{background-image:url(http://media.businesslive.ro/wp-content/uploads/creative-monkeyz.png);}
.back{background-image:(http://media-cache-ec0.pinterest.com/avatars/artalacafea-1347781782_600.jpg)}
</style>
<div class="face"><div>
```

An example of my initial code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7AgbX/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming this is what you want..

used [toogleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to toggle the class ('front' and 'back')on `click()` function..

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7AgbX/2/)

```
$(".face").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('back');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Using css3 you can do this very easily
Here is a example. http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/